# CollectionView doesn't update with ObservableCollection as Sourcee

Tags: c#, xaml, observablecollection, maui, collectionview

I have a CollectionView in A ScrollView.
I want to bind the Soource to a ObservableCollection in my ViewModel.

Here's the Code of my Xaml:

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="vm:TodayViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadStandInsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding StandIns}" SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:StandIn" BackgroundColor="Red">
                                <Frame HeightRequest="50" >
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource BaseLabel}" Text="{Binding Stunde}" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource BaseLabel}" Text="{Binding Fach}" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource BaseLabel}" Text="{Binding Raum}" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource BaseLabel}" Text="{Binding Lehrer}" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource BaseLabel}" Text="{Binding Art}" FontSize="10"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>
```

Here's my Xaml.cs:

```
TodayViewModel _viewModel;
public TodayPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = _viewModel = new TodayViewModel();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    _viewModel.OnAppearing();
}
```

Here's my View Model:

```
  public Command LoadStandInsCommand { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<StandIn> StandIns { get; }
public TodayViewModel()
        {
            StandIns = new ObservableCollection<StandIn>();
            LoadStandInsCommand = new Command(async ()=> await ExecuteLoadStandInsCommand());
        }

async Task ExecuteLoadStandInsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                StandIns.Clear();
                if (loadListToday)
                {
                    sIList.AddRange(gh.GetStandInsToday());
                }
                else
                {
                    sIList.AddRange(gh.GetStandInsTomorrow());
                }
                foreach (StandIn item in sIList)
                {
                    if (item.Klasse == pN.Klasse || item.Lehrer == pN.Klasse)
                    {
                        StandIns.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

As a info I'm writting a .netMaui App.
The Problem is that the CollectionView doesn't show any Items, but StandIns is filled with 39 Items.
I don't know why it's not working.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try setting IsBusy = true outside the Command only

Comment: @Benl That didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tested manually adding some hardcoded items, directly in constructor? To verify that xaml displays them correctly. Also, you don't show the declaration line of TodayViewModel. Does it inherit from a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged? If not, make sure it implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Maybe that is necessary for ObservableCollection to work. If it already does, you could try `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StandIns));` after filling it. (Though that shouldn't be needed.)

Comment: If you have posted your complete ViewModel class definition, instead of this part, that you think is relevant, but actually is not, you would have gotten your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and did some improvements. It can work now.

Here's the Code of my `Xaml`:

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="vm:TodayViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadStandInsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding StandIns}"  SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <!-- I changed the style format you can change the label style here-->
                    <StackLayout.Resources>
                        <!-- Implicit style -->
                        <Style TargetType="Label">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#1976D2" />
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                        </Style>
                    </StackLayout.Resources>

                    <Frame HeightRequest="200" >
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Stunde}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Fach}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Raum}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Lehrer}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding Art}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

Here is the code in `Xaml.cs`:

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = new TodayViewModel();
    }
```

I used the static data to test and you can remove them.
Here is the code in my `ViewModel`:

```
 internal class TodayViewModel
    {
       /* public Command LoadStandInsCommand { get; }*/
        public ObservableCollection<StandIn> StandIns { get;  }
        public TodayViewModel()
        {
            StandIns = new ObservableCollection<StandIn>();

            StandIns.Add(new StandIn() { Art = "art1", Fach = "fach1", Lehrer = "lehrer1", Raum = "raum1", Stunde = "stunde1" });
            StandIns.Add(new StandIn() { Art = "art1", Fach = "fach1", Lehrer = "lehrer1", Raum = "raum1", Stunde = "stunde1" });
            StandIns.Add(new StandIn() { Art = "art1", Fach = "fach1", Lehrer = "lehrer1", Raum = "raum1", Stunde = "stunde1" });
            StandIns.Add(new StandIn() { Art = "art1", Fach = "fach1", Lehrer = "lehrer1", Raum = "raum1", Stunde = "stunde1" });
            /*  LoadStandInsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadStandInsCommand());*/


        }

      /*  async Task ExecuteLoadStandInsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                StandIns.Clear();
                if (loadListToday)
                {
                    sIList.AddRange(gh.GetStandInsToday());
                }
                else
                {
                    sIList.AddRange(gh.GetStandInsTomorrow());
                }
                foreach (StandIn item in sIList)
                {
                    if (item.Klasse == pN.Klasse || item.Lehrer == pN.Klasse)
                    {
                        StandIns.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }*/
    }
```

Here is my `Model`:

```
  internal class StandIn
    {
        public string Stunde { get; set; }
        public string Fach { get; set; }
        public string Raum { get; set; }
        public string Lehrer { get; set; }
        public string Art { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the final view of the project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me out. I think the problem was firstly the highrequest  of the frame which was way to small and that the basestyle didn't exist. I forgot to delete it.